# How can I insert each element in a 1D array into a new row in an SQL Database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, arrays, insert

I have an array containing a list of file paths that I want to insert into an SQL database.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test Folder");
```

I am confident in setting up and connecting to the database, I just can't figure out how to take each element and place it in a new row in the database.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which technology you are using (*Please note that when inserting lots of rows the use of `SqlBulkCopy` is recommended*).

**ADO.NET**

```
foreach (var path in filePaths)
{
   var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytable(col1) VALUES(@param1)", connection);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", path);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**LINQ-to-SQL**

```
var projection = filePaths.Select(a => new MyTable() { Col1 = a });
myContext.InsertAllOnSubmit(projection);
myContext.SubmitChanges();
```

**LINQ-to-Entities**

```
foreach (var path in filePaths)
{
   myModel.MyTable.AddObject(new MyTable() { Col1 = path });
}
myModel.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(string fp in filePaths)
{
   InsertIntoDb(fp);
}

//Method
public void InsertIntoDb(string insert)
{
   SqlConnection con = //Setup DB connection
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   command.Connection = con;
   command.CommandText = "Insert @insert into Table";
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insert", insert);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This leaves out a lot, but it should point you in the right direction.  Essentially, you want to set up your connection, instantiate a SqlCommand object where the command text is the SQL Text to insert your value (Better would be a stored procedure or some other sanitized way to insert the data to avoid Sql Injection), and then call ExecuteNonQuery() to insert the actual data.

Comment: this is one way and it will work, but if array is few thousands rows, it will have performance issue.

Comment: Huge performance issues. Using an implementation like this could be the distinguisher between the query taking 0.38 seconds and 7 hours for the same datasets. And yes, these numbers are accurate, because we found out the hard way! Just add an exert indicating that you should use sqlBulkcopy when dealing with large datasets and your answer is no up to par.

Comment: This is true.  My presumption was a fairly small dataset.  Large datasets require different methods to insert.  SqlBulkInsert is probably the best of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

you will have to project your data into a DataTable, DataRow[], etc. OR [IDataReader](http://forums.asp.net/t/1188854.aspx/1) (which is more efficient - refer this discussion and example) in order to use SqlBulkCopy